# Fill WPF textbox from other wpf window datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, window

I'm a beginner with C#. In my little project I have 3 WPF windows: MainWindow, Window2, Window3.
MainWindow is reserved for the Log In. If it is successfull, I see Window2, that has a datagrid with certain fields (Project ID, Project name) and getting data from SQL table. I want to view any of the selected data row in some textbox in Window3. Do you have any piece of code for doing that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please show what you attempted so far, with code samples when relevant. This is not a code writing service, so, unless you do so this question will get closed down.

Comment: Here're tips on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).